# How to display rate value using stars

Tags: php

i tried. but it not success full.. please give me solution..

php code

```
<?php
function getReviews($con){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM review";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<div class=' col-md-12 comment-box'>";
            echo "<div class='left-comm col-md-2'>";
            echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='images/article/avatar3.png'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='right-comm col-md-6'>";
            echo "<p class='user-name'>".$row['email']."</p>";
            echo for ($i=0; $i <$row['rating'] ; $i++) { 
        echo "*";
    }"<br>";
            echo $row['review']."<br>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div><br>";
?>
```

i want to display rate value using stars.in this function.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) database extension in new code **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7. If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions. [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: If it's not doing what you want it to do, what is it doing? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
  echo for ($i=0; $i <$row['rating'] ; $i++) { 
        echo "*";
    }"<br>";
```

to:

```
for ($i=0; $i <$row['rating'] ; $i++) { 
    echo "*";
}
echo "<br />";
```

Comment: i tried it but it give this error.....                                            Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR)

Comment: looks like you have syntax error. Have you closed the statement above the `for` line with a semicolon? Post your latest code here.

Comment: i tried this one.. but not work.
echo "<script>
             $i = $row['rating'];
             for ($i=0; $i <5 ; $i++) { 
         echo "*";
         }
</script>";

Comment: for ($i=0; $i <$row['rating'] ; $i++) { 
         echo "*";
     }

thank you very much buddy that work...